# NVENC: Number of IDR slices per IDR refresh

Tags: nvidia, h.264, video-encoding, nvenc

I was examining a h264 bitstream I generated with [Nvidia Video Encoder](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-video-codec-sdk) (NVENC) and notices that each IDR update contains not a single IDR nal, but 4 of them.

[image]

I don't understand why there is a need in 4 IDR nals per update.
I am trying to find a way to reduce that number to a single IDR slice per update.
In NVENC config I use `idrPeriod` to tell the encoder the frequency of update, but I can't find a way to control number of IDR nals per update.